# How To Convert Synchronous Functions To Asynchronous Functions In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, synchronous

Functions in pure **JavaScript** are **synchronous** by default. Is there a way to convert **synchronous** functions to become **asynchronous**.

*Note: I don't want to use **setTimeout** function (Or setImmediate In Node.js)*. Just ECMAScript specs. Tried to add async keyword but the result is the same synchronous behavior.

The Example below illustrates the default behavior.

**Code:**

```js
console.log("start");

function countTo100Mill() {
  for(i=0; i <= 100000000; i++) {
    if(i === 100000000) {
       console.log("count to 100mill complete");
       }
  }
}

function countTo100() {
  for(i=0; i <= 100; i++) {
    if(i === 100) {
       console.log("count to 100 complete");
       }
  }
}

countTo100Mill();

countTo100();

console.log("end");
```

**Default Behaviour:**

The function `countTo100Mill` will run before `countTo100` no matter the delay.

**What I Want To Achieve:**

I want a way to convert the functions defined in the code above to run asynchronously so that `countTo100` will complete followed by `countTo100Mill`.

Comment: You need to use `setTimeout`/`setInterval`/`setImmediate` - there is literally no other way

Comment: @slebetman Disagree, this is achievable (but really weird) with `await`

Comment: Promises do provide some EcmaScript-native asynchronous functions to use, but it would work just the same as using `setTimeout`/`setImmediate`.

Comment: When you added the `async` keyword, did you also `await` anything? Only that makes the rest of the function body run later.

Comment: @Bergi no I did not add the await keyword. Is it not supposed to work without the await keyword

Comment: @claOnline `await` does nothing to your code. I was in the middle of writing an answer before this was marked as duplicate. If you really want to run your code in a different thread (which is what you imply you want, not simply make it asynchronous - run in unpredictable order) then you can use something like `worker_threads` - https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html#worker_threads_worker_threads or some other threading library like `webworker-threads` from npm

Comment: @claOnline No, an `async function` starts running its code immediately when called. Only `await`ing something brings in asynchrony. But I would suggest to drop the `async`/`await` syntactic sugar for this exercise and use promises with their `then` method explicitly.